# HTTP Function C# SQL ASYNC

Tags: c#, sql, http, asynchronous, triggers

I have an http trigger that calls a support function to perform a SQL update on some JSON. I made a mistake in the support function and used command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync() by accident. This code ran just fine locally in VS Studio, 100% of the time. But, when I published to Azure the function would work once. The only way to make it work again was start/stop the function. I performed a memory dump and saw there was one thread running. The HTTP request always returned 200, even though it only changed the data once.

Now my question. The Azure HTTP function does not wait for the threads to finish before exiting? I am just trying to understand better Azure threading.

Thanks

```
  public static class SetNotificationConfig
{
    [FunctionName("SetNotificationConfig")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(requestBody);
            var tem = data["NotificationConfig"];
            string notificationConfig = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tem);
            SchedulerSupport.SetNotificationConfigJSON(1, notificationConfig);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult("Error updating notification configuration: " + ex.Message);
        }
        return new OkResult();
    }
}

    public static void SetNotificationConfigJSON(int storeId, string notificationConfig)
    {
        if (notificationConfig.Length > 0)
        {
            using SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SchedulerSupport.ConnectionStr());
            connection.Open();
            var queryString = "Update SchedulerConfig Set ConfigInfo = JSON_MODIFY(ConfigInfo, '$.NotificationConfig', JSON_QUERY(@notificationConfig)) Where StoreId = @StoreId";
            using SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            try
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StoreId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));
                command.Parameters["@StoreId"].Value = storeId;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NotificationConfig", notificationConfig);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `But, when I published to Azure the function would work once`  How do you know this? do you have some kind of logging? What does it show?  Because if you're re-using the payload, could it be that each time it runs it just overwrites your DB data with same values coz they are what you keep sending?

Comment: First, thank you. I had SQL enterprise manager open on the row in the database I was trying to update. So I would re-execute fetch in SQL Enterprise manager and examined the results. If running in VS Studio on Windows 10, it always worked ok. I was quite confused why working local and not cloud. In cloud it runs exactly once. But, the function returns success, even if database was not updated. In Azure portal, I stop/start function. Runs once. I know I made an error, just trying to understand the results

Comment: I wonder what is the purpose of catching and throwing in SetNotificationConfigJSON.

Comment: Serilog or some sort of logging is going to be added for recording SQL errors in near future.